# MFC , Any solution to parse ftp response file list line

Tags: parsing, mfc, ftp

Have any library solution to parse as follow file list string

```
0x001d8f60 "-rw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 YS_LIANG
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 2014-05-08 [][][] - [][][][]
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 FTPClient-WinCE
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 GRAPHIC
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 S8521 V1.6.17
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 S8521V1.7.0
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 Storage Card2
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 UltraEdit 18.20.0.1021
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 usb wireless driver
drw-------   1 root     root     000000000 Jun 30 2014 Windows7 ActiveSync
-rw-------   1 root     root     101384240 Jun 28 2013 avira_free_antivirus_zhtw.exe
-rw-------   1 root     root     000564736 Jun 21 2011 ComTest.exe
-rw-------   1 root     root     000000189 Feb 10 2014 ComTest.INI
-rw-------   1 root     root     006465536 May 5 2014 DR12AsyncSocket.exe
-r"
```

Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is split each line on `space`

Comment: if the folder name include space... the solution maybe unuse

Comment: Parsing this is really not *that* difficult. The first 8 elements never contain spaces (or can usernames contain spaces ?). The folder name or file name is the only element that can contain spaces. So the first 8 elements are "permissions" to "year" and the rest is necessarily the file name or the directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I got the solution.

```
while(true)
{
nNewLineIdx = strRespFileList.Find(_T("\r\n"));
if(nNewLineIdx == -1)
{
    break;
} 
    // TODO : Save in CStringArray
}

// Parse CString line of CStringArray
for(int loop=0; loop<CStringArray.GetCount();loop++)
{
int strLineLen = CStringArray.GetAt(loop).GetLength();
int nSerchLoc = 0;
int nStep = 0;
while(nSerchLoc < strLineLen)
{
    CString strTok = CStringArray.GetAt(loop).Tokenize(_T(" "), nSerchLoc);
    // TODO : Save cut information
}
}
```